# pdo insert image into database directly - always inserting BLOB - 0B

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, blob

I'm trying to insert the image into mysql database table directly. In my database I'm always getting [BLOB - 0B]. it doesn't insert images into table. I didn't get any error too. I'm confused..

**PHP**

```
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
    ini_set('display_errors',1);
    error_reporting(-1);

    include('config.php');
     if (isset($_FILES['image']) && $_FILES['image']['size'] > 0) 
      { 
          $tmpName  = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];  

          $fp = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
          $data = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
          $data = addslashes($data);
          fclose($fp);
      } 

      try
        {
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO images ( picture ) VALUES ( '$data' )");
//          $stmt->bindParam(1, $data, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
            $conn->errorInfo();
            $stmt->execute();
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            'Error : ' .$e->getMessage();
        }
```

**HTML**

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post">
<input id="image" name="image" type="file" />
<input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

Comment: Does the $data variable hold the data you expect (if you dump it)? What type is the picture field in the table?

Comment: @RonniSkansing : its `BLOB`

Comment: _sidenote_: inserting blob is not a good idea,simply store the image in some folder in server and then save the url in table

Comment: @user790454 [It depends](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay).

Comment: @FerozAkbar Why? There appears to be no valid reason to say this, only a 50/50 preference based on personal tastes.

Comment: @Cassandra i am talking about the other 50

Comment: @FerozAkbar Sorry I don't follow you. I'd like to learn why exactly storing a file of any sort, inside MySQL, is not good. Backed up with reason, not preference.

Answer (score 7):

You almost got it, you want `PDO::PARAM_LOB` to be a file pointer which you created above, not the result of reading the fp

```
if (isset($_FILES['image']) && $_FILES['image']['size'] > 0) 
{ 
   $tmpName  = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];  
   $fp = fopen($tmpName, 'rb'); // read binary

   $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO images ( picture ) VALUES ( ? )");
   $stmt->bindParam(1, $fp, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
   $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: no. now it doesn't insert any datas into the field. Now I didn't get `BLOB-0B` in my table..

Comment: @Beginner - are you sure that the `$_FILES` array is populated?

Comment: oh sorry. problem is not in my php coding. this is my fault. I missed to mention this on my form `enctype="multipart/form-data"` . anyway thanks mate...

Comment: @Beginner - if this answers your question you should +1 and accept. You could also edit your post to mention the `enctype` change.